# clang unused value in expression

Tags: c, warnings, clang

Clang seems to be giving me a warning that a a char is unused in an expression, here's the entire section of code:

```
int yeller(const char * channel) {
char *p, *q;
q = p = MAKE_COPY(temp->bind_chan);
while ((p = next_in_comma_list(q, &q))) {
if (!p || !*p)
break;
if (!my_stricmp(p, channel))
return tmp;
```

Specifically this line:

```
q = p = MAKE_COPY(temp->bind_chan);
```

Although the value stored to 'p' is used in the enclosing expression, the value is never actually read from 'p'

I am obviously evaluating it in the while loop, is this really a 'bug' or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Give the exact error clang spits out.

Comment: I don't even understand why you ask. Your first assignment to `p` is superfluous, that's what the compiler is telling you. It just makes no sense, so remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Clang is giving you a hint that you might have an error in your code.

The code assigns value to `p` and this value isn't used anywhere before it gets overwritten, which looks strange and the code snippet doing this should be revisited. In the `while` loop that follows you are overwriting the contents of `p` without ever using its previous value.

This warning can be a life-safer in the code like this:

```
Status status = do_some_job();
...
(some code where status isn't checked)
...
status = do_some_ther_job();
```

Which is most likely a programmer error, because in most of the cases if a function returns status, it should be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Clang is trying to convince you to write better code, listen to it.

I think the semantic of your code snippet is better met with something like this

```
char *q = MAKE_COPY(temp->bind_chan);
for (char *p; (p = next_in_comma_list(q, &q));) {
 ...
}
```

that is using initialization instead of assignment where this is possible and making the iteration variable local to the scope where it is used.

*Edit:* This uses features that are not present in acient C, AKA C89, but where introduced to the language in 1999. Clang should work fine with it since it uses C99 per default.

Comment: FWIW the above is only for c99 mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "only" C99 mode? The current C standard is C11.